# Range.Cells property syntax

Tags: vba, excel

I'm confused by the Range.Cells property. According to MSN documentation:

[Range.Cells Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx)

The syntax is supposed to be `expression .Cells`

Yet at the example further down the code is not following this syntax but seems to use `Cells` as a function:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 3)).Font.Italic = True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When no dot `.` precedes a `Cells` or `Range` method, this is called an *unqualified range reference*; Excel's VBA wraps it automatically to the sheet that is currently active.

```
Cells(1, 1) <==> Activesheet.Cells(1, 1)
Range("A1") <==> Activesheet.Range("A1")
```

However, this is considered *bad practice* and it should be avoided because it leads to random issues and bugs; the code's behavior depends on what sheet the user currently has on top in Excel's GUI. Experienced developers always avoid it as much as possible and use *qualified ranges*; ie

`Worksheets("someSheetName").Cells(1, 1)`.

Comment: `Cells` is actually a property not a method and in the given example it is a `Range` property. So which is the active `Range`? There doesn't seem to be one since `Range` is just about to be accessed, so how does it make sense to use and unqualified `Cells` property if there is no active `Range`?

Comment: Properties are special type of methods and the latter is generally used in OOP to designate all *callables* of a class (VBA Sub, Function, Property etc). For the second question, in your example, both `Range` and `Cells` refer to the `ActiveSheet` , considered as a *global variable* in Excel VBA.

Comment: Understood. Still the linked MSN documentation is confusing because the `Cells` property in the code snippet is actually referencing the `ActiveSheet` and not the `Range`.

Comment: Yes it is very confusing before one gets enough used to these intricacies. Sometimes people make a mistake such as `mySheet.Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(4,4))` and get a runtime error when the activesheet is not the `mySheet`. This snippet tries to compose a range from mySheet, composed between cells of another sheet (the active one) ==> runtime error. Your best friend in these situations is the `With` directive.